# swiper in react trying to fade images

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying this code but images are't moving.   They have arrows, but not moving. I want a fade and an auto change of the images.  Also, does anyone know if this is the best lib to use with react typescript to get images to fade and then underneath I may have images also moving left and right

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, Autoplay } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/a11y'; // If using A11y module
import React from 'react';
import  SwiperCore  from 'swiper';
import SwiperInstance  from 'swiper/types';

//import { SwiperCore, SwiperInstance } from 'swiper';

// Install required Swiper modules
//SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]);
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, Autoplay]);

const ImageCarousel = () => {
    // Define your array of image URLs
    const images = [
        '/image1.jpg',
        '/image2.jpg',
        '/image3.jpg',
        // Add more image URLs here as needed
    ];

    // Define the type for the swiper parameter in onSwiper
    const handleSwiper = (swiper: any) => {
        console.log(swiper); // Now 'swiper' will have the correct type
    };

    return (
        <Swiper
            spaceBetween={50}
            slidesPerView={1}
            navigation
            pagination={{ clickable: true }}
            scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
            autoplay={{ delay: 2000, disableOnInteraction: false }} // Enable autoplay and adjust the delay as needed
            loop // Enable loop to make the carousel infinite
            onSwiper={handleSwiper} // Pass the handleSwiper function
            onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
        >
            {images.map((imageUrl, index) => (
                <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                    <img src={imageUrl} alt={`Image ${index + 1}`} />
                </SwiperSlide>
            ))}
        </Swiper>
    );
};

export default ImageCarousel;
```